# Jakarta Server Faces project templates

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces, jboss-tools

The jar file org.jboss.tools.common.projecttemplates_3.17 only contains templates up to jsf-2.3. Is there any templates for jsf-3.0?

I’m trying to create a dynamic web project using Jakarta Server Faces because we are converting our Primefaces app to Jakarta but the maximum version shown under Eclipse project properties -> Project Facets is JSF 2.3. Do I have to ignore this and setup the faces-config.xml manually?

I'm using:
Eclipse 2023-06-M1
Wildfly preview 28
Jboss tools 4.27
Jboss tools extensions 4.27

I also could not find the projecttemplates jar file in the nightly build for Jboss tools 4.28. Is it hidden somewhere?

Comment: Hmm I would expect that Jboss has updated their tooling by now to support Faces 4 / Jakarta but maybe they haven't?  That would be surprised considering they have been working on WildFly 27 and 28 Jakarta support for a while now and MyFaces and Mojarra 4.0 are both out.

Comment: In eclipse select File -> New -> Dynamic Web Project. Choose WildFly 28 as the Target runtime and Click on the Modify button next to Configuration. Only JavaServer Faces 2.3 is shown and not Jakarta Server Faces 4.0

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the Jboss Tools to me.